# bind Asserts on methods to property

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

i have a method, validating that the combination of certain inputs is valid (*e.g. elderly-discount option chosen and birthday shows age above n*).

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message="you are too young for this option")
 */
public function isElderlyOptionValid()
{
    return 
    ($this->getElderlyOption() && $this->getAgeFromBirthday() <= 60);
}
```

Now i want the error to show for the elderly-discount option and not as a general error for the entity/form. So i would need something like:

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message="you are too young for this option", bindTo="elderlyOption")
 */
public function isElderlyOptionValid()
{
    return 
    ($this->getElderlyOption() && $this->getAgeFromBirthday() <= 60);
}
```

I did read once that this is possible but can't finde the article again.

Comment: And by replacing `bindTo` by `atPath` ?

Comment: @JulienBourdic: That throws an error "atPath" is not an option :-(

Answer (score 1):

UniqueEntity have error_path and use `atPath` inside UniqueEntityValidator but I dont think its possible to change path for all validators.

Probably you can extend this validator and add `atPath` functionality, **but**

maybe **[this is what you're looking for](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-mapping)**.
Forms have `error_mapping` property and you can "redirect" your error to field.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'error_mapping' => array(
            'matchingCityAndZipCode' => 'city',
        ),
    ));
}
```